# Сделать из строки массив

Tags: php

Как из "123456", сделать [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да вы правы, без разделителя нельзя воспользоваться, протестировал. Ваш вариант с `$test = str_split("123456");` работает отлично

Answer (score 2):

Просто вот так:

```
$test = str_split("123456");
```

Скорее всего в массиве будут строковые значения поэтом придётся ещё из преобразовать в числа, если нужно, например так:

```
$test = array_map('intval', $test);
```

Answer (score 0):

в php *динамическая типизация*, по сему прям четких границ между типами нет.
любая строка изначально может использоваться как массив безо всяких подготовок\обработок

```
<?
$a = 'abcde';
echo $a[1]; // echo b

// более того, к строкам применима ин\дэ"крементация
echo ++$a[2]; // echo d
?>
```

точно актуально для какой то из 5ых версий, возможно в свежих пофиксили, но это не точно.